# Cannot open X display `(null)'. **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

input:

```
gs myPSFile.ps
```

output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Cannot open X display `(null)'.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
```

why?

I have windows 10.

I'm using git bash to ssh into my school's internal tux server.

What I tried:

I saw 3 or 4 other duplicate questions on many other sites. I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently either your Windows 10 system does not have an "X11 server" software that could receive and display graphics data from X11 GUI applications, or if you have one set up, your SSH client did not automatically establish "X11 forwarding" that would allow the remote `gs` application to send its display windows to your Windows system's screen.

A SSH session in its basic form is a text-only connection: the X11 graphics forwarding is optional.

Remote sessions also won't automatically have access to the server's local X11 display either: either your file popping up on the server's local screen in the school's server room would be a nuisance to someone using the local screen, or if the server room is unoccupied, would serve no useful purpose at all. Besides, a server system might not even have a screen connected to it at any given time, unless needed for hardware troubleshooting.

Comment: How do I get an X11 server software on my Windows 10 system?

Comment: That is technically a separate question that is out of scope for Unix & Linux StackExchange. But there are free X11 server solutions for Windows; [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) is probably one of the more user-friendly ones.